# How do I reject an offer?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

Recently I got an offer letter from one of the top companies. However, because of some unexpected situations I want to reject the offer. In the mail I've explained all the reasons, but I am finding it difficult to find a sentence for the end of the mail. Should I say "I apologize for the inconvenience" or "Sorry to inform you that I am rejecting the offer"

Would usage of 'reject' be rude?  Could someone suggest an exact sentence or a set of sentences? Thank you.

Comment: Asking for suggestions of this type is not a good fit for this site. You should ask at an etiqutte site.

Comment: This might be a better for for [this Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/professional-matters?referrer=t0qzW5ESkS-JS6wd42Y-3w2), once it gets going.

Comment: My advice is to make clear in the first line that you reject the offer.  Don't wait until after the explanations to do that!

Comment: You should pick up the phone and tell them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write for example

> I apologize for being unable to accept this offer due to these
>   unforeseen circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

After explaining why I don't want to take up the offer, I'd close my letter by saying...

*Thanking you for your understanding in this matter*.